# Do I need to call SuspendLayout for every child control?

Tags: c#, winforms

Can't find any information about this. My controls are rendering extremely slow and I noticed I'm not calling `SuspendLayout` when doing major updates.

What I'm in doubt is, since the top level control contains controls which contain other controls and so on, will calling `SuspendLayout` on my top control also suspend layout for every nested control or do I need to call it for each of them?

Comment: I would guess that's not the problem.  Is this when you are loading a form, or just in general?  And are these custom controls you've created?

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Yes, these are custom controls and I'm trying to find other problems, but if you know the answer to my question please let me know since I wanted to know this before anyway, and also so I can discard this option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at this MSDN article - [Practical Tips For Boosting The Performance Of Windows Forms Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx).

> **Text from article** : Remember that SuspendLayout only prevents Layout
>   events from being performed for that particular control. If controls
>   are added to a panel, for example, SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout must
>   be called for the panel and not for the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess would be no, but my advice would be to try anyway and see if it helps.  These questions might provide you with a solution: [How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children), [Winforms: SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout is not enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835100/winforms-suspendlayout-resumelayout-is-not-enough)