# BeginUpdate / EndUpdate for DataGridView request

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I need to freeze (stop redrawing) DataGridView while I processing fields update.

Is there something like BeginUpdate to temporary freeze DataGridView

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the extension methods in Adam Robinson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778095/windows-forms-using-backgroundimage-slows-down-drawing-of-the-forms-controls).

Use them with your DataGridView like this:

```
yourDataGridView.SuspendDrawing();

// update your fields.

yourDataGridView.ResumeDrawing();
```