# Add datagridviewrow with mixed column types using addrange

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a datagridview that gets populated with data from a database, the last two columns are a combobox and a button.

To prevent flickering I use `Rows.AddRange` to add all the rows at once (the entire procedure is in a backgroundworker)

My question is how do I add the values to the dropdownbox. The items are just a list of stings so no need to datasource it.

```
DataTable dt = db.fill(query, dbpars);
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cbox.Items.Add("--Please Select--");
cbox.Items.Add("Generate");
cbox.Items.Add("Ignore");

List<DataGridViewRow> rowList = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow drow = new DataGridViewRow();
    drow.CreateCells(dgvClientWork);

    drow.Cells[0].Value = row[0];
    drow.Cells[1].Value = row[1];
    drow.Cells[2].Value = row[2];
    drow.Cells[3].Value = row[3];
    drow.Cells[4].Value = row[4];
    drow.Cells[5].Value = row[5];

    //((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvClientWork.Columns[6]).Items.Add("2");
    //var td = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    //drow.Cells[6] = td;
    //((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) drow.Cells[6]).Items.Add("WFT");

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell td = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvClientWork.Rows[0].Cells[6];

    td.Items.Add("--Please Select--");
    td.Items.Add("Generate");
    td.Items.Add("Ignore");

    //td.Items.AddRange(new object[]{"--Please Select--", "Generate", "Ignore"});

    //var t = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)cbox.Clone();
    //drow.Cells.Add(t);
    //drow.Cells[6] = t;
    //drow.Cells[6].Value = "--Please Select--";
    /*drow.Cells[7].Value = btn;*/

    rowList.Add(drow);
}

Action action = () => dgvClientWork.Rows.AddRange(rowList.ToArray());
dgvClientWork.Invoke(action);
```

As you can see I have attempted several things but the combobox is always blank.

Comment: *To prevent flickering I use `Rows.AddRange`* - you can also use [`BeginUpdate`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5817632/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr thanks for that, sadly that won't solve the issue I'm getting :(

Comment: That's why I am not posting an answer for you ;) Perhaps you are not adding row [correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10063770/1997232)?

Comment: Where are you performing this code, in the form constructor?

Comment: @OhBeWise within a background worker which runs on form load

Answer (score 0):

If I duplicated your problem correctly, if you check the last row in your dgv, that drop down will have multiples of your added items.

To fix, change this line of code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell td = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvClientWork.Rows[0].Cells[6];
```

To this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell td = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)drow.Cells[6];
```

Edit: If you want the cells defaulted, just adding

```
td.Value = "--Please Select--";
```

then worked for me.

Edit:  On a side note, when you created your DGV and added the columns, I would have just created the ComboBoxColumn and set its DataSource to a list of the same strings you've set in your code.  This way any newly added rows by the user will also have the same combobox source.  As of right now, any new rows will have empty comboboxes.