# Loop is taking around 10 minutes in vb

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, loops

```
 For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In DgvItemList.Rows
            drow.Cells("strSrNo").Value = drow.Index + 1
        Next
```

I have more than 3500 records in DgvItemList. I just give to numbering to that records but it tool 9 to 10 minutes for that.

How to reduce this time ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817632/beginupdate-endupdate-for-datagridview-request, maybe? Windows messages make it Windows-specific, though.

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? As in: *why* do you need to assign what looks like some sort of serial number to data that is already in the grid? EDIT: also, is your grid bound to a DataTable or something?

Comment: yes data is binding by datatable. I just need to give number to the row .

Comment: You state that the DGV is bound to a DataTable.  Do you really need the row number stored in the DataTable or is this a _Display Only_ requirement?  If it is only for display, you can use an unbound column and paint the row number in code.  If you stay with your current code, determine the column index of "strSrNo" before the loop and use the value in the loop; this will prevent looking up the column index on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Two things. Each time you change the value, it could cause the DataGridView to update, so just before your loop, add

```
DgvItemList.SuspendLayout
```

and after the loop, add

```
    DgvItemList.ResumeLayout
```

You could also change the loop to a Parallel.For loop, so your final code would be something like

```
DgvItemList.SuspendLayout 
Parallel.For(0, DgvItemList.Rows.Count, Sub(index As Integer)
                                        DgvItemList.Rows(index).Cells("strSrNo").Value = DgvItemList.Rows(index).Index + 1
                                            End Sub)
DgvItemList.ResumeLayout
```

Try it with just the Suspend and Resume layout first. You may not get a vast amount of improvement from the parallelization. Worth a go though.

Comment: Shouldn't end condition of the Parallel.For be the row count minus 1?

Comment: I've never used `Parallel.For`, but doesn't it require you to invoke when accessing the UI, just like with regular threads/tasks?

Comment: @dwilliss no. Just to confuse people, a regular for.next loop  say from 0 to 100 will loop 101 times, but a parallel.for loop will only execute from 0 to 99, so you don't need to subtract 1 from the end value in the case of zero based indexes. On the other side of the coin of course, if the end of your loop is obtained from array.getupperbound, you might need to add 1

Comment: @VisualVincent Perhaps, but I'm guessing that as the code only changes data and possibly doesn't call any methods that change the UI there is no cross thread problem. It seems to work fine. If you put in something like a call to the .Update method, it does hang with a cross threading error.

Comment: But `TextBox.Text` is also data, yet it throws an exception because it causes the text box to be redrawn. The value of the cell must also be redrawn when you change it, so I think you would normally have to invoke here as well (unless the DGV has a different way of detecting changes).

Comment: Timing is the same as before after using resume and suspend layout @DavidWilson

Comment: @VisualVincent I know. It's odd. I've run it on a small dgv row count and it seems to work.

Comment: @Bhoomi Does the parallel.For improve things?