# Add rows to DataGridView without freezing GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I want to display a table. Data for table must to be precalculated and it is heavy calculation. Also result table is long.
I want to provide acces to part of data while another part is calculated in the background.

I wrote background worker for calculation and DataGridView for display. Sometimes worker submit new rows via ProgressChangedEvent. I am tried to add this rows at bottom. 
My problem starts when I tried add new rows at bottom. My UI is freezes.

Here is how I initialize DataGridView:

```
private void InitDataGridView() 
{
    BindingList<TableRow> tableRows = new BindingList<TableRow>();
    dataGridView.DataSource = tableRows;
}
```

and here is how I adding new rows at bottom in ProgressChangedEvent

```
private void UpdateDataGridView (List<Items> newItems)
{
    BindingList<TableRow> dataSource = (BindingList<TableRow>)this.dataGridView.DataSource;
    foreach (var item in newItems)
        dataSource.Add(new TableRow(item));
}
```

I think that problem is because adding one row initiate redrawing of the table.
But I don't found AddRange for BindingList or mechanism to stop rendering temporary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5817632/3110834) also you can implement [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which can stop raise `ListChanged` event.

Comment: it looks interesting. Thanks for direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a new item to the list, `BindingList` raises a `ListChanged` which leads to updating `DataGridView`. To make updating of `DataGridView` more efficient, as an option you can stop raising `ListChanged` event of the `BindingList`. This way you can turn it off before adding items and then turn it on and raise the event just after adding a group of items to the list.

Here is an implementation which supports turning `ListChanged` event on/off:

```
public class MyBindingList<T>:BindingList<T>
{
    public bool EnableChangeNotifications { get; set; }
    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(EnableChangeNotifications)
            base.OnListChanged(e);
    }
}
```

And for example, disable the event when adding items::

```
list.EnableChangeNotifications = false;
//Add new items to the list using a loop or something else.
```

Then to showing changes in `DataGridView`, enable the event and raise it:

```
list.EnableChangeNotifications = true;
list.ResetBindings();
```

Comment: It is perfect solution. The only one unwanted visual effect have place (selected column reset to 0 each time). But it is not a problem.

Comment: You can store the selected cell index before `ResetBindings` the list and set it again after `ResetBindings`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property to `None` or `DisplayedCells`, as well as set on the `AutoSizeMode` on each column:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in thisGrid.Columns)
{
    c.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
}
```

Try toggling this before and after binding, and when updating.

Also, you can try what is suggested on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35984368/3618341) and enable double buffering:

```
if (!System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
{
  Type dgvType = dataGridView1.GetType();
  PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  pi.SetValue(dataGridView1, value, null);
}
```