# VB.NET Hide Control Updates Behind Panel

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding (and removing) controls from a `FlowLayoutPanel` and am noticing some serious levels of flickering. I've attempted to cover the `FlowLayoutPanel` with a `Panel` with "Loading" written on it, but the controls are loaded before the `Panel` is displayed, so it is still visible.

Here's the code I'm using (Comments are in the code):

```
   Private Sub ViewOrders_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Panel2.BringToFront() 'This covers the FlowLayoutPanel in which the custom controls are added

        dgvViewOrders.DataSource = dtOrders

        For i = 0 To dgvViewOrders.Columns.Count - 1
            dgvViewOrders.Columns(i).Visible = False
        Next

        dgvViewOrders.Columns(0).Visible = True
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(2).Visible = True
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(10).Visible = True
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(12).Visible = True
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(12).DisplayIndex = 1
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(2).DisplayIndex = 2

        dgvViewOrders.Columns(10).HeaderText = "£ Total"
        dgvViewOrders.Columns(12).HeaderText = "Date/Time"

        CreateSecondPOC(Nothing, Nothing) 'This creates the custom controls

        If dgvViewOrders.RowCount > 0 Then
            dgvViewOrders.ClearSelection()
            dgvViewOrders.CurrentCell = dgvViewOrders.Rows(0).Cells(0)
            dgvViewOrders.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If


        LoadingComplete = True
        Panel2.SendToBack() 'Hide Panel so custom controls can be used


    End Sub
```

I've also attempted something very similar using a `BackgroundWorker` but it had the same effect.

Surely there's an easy approach to this that I am missing?

Comment: Add Panel2.Update().  Or [use this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/778133/17034).

Comment: How about calling `SuspendLayout` and afterward `ResumeLayout` on the `FlowLayoutPanel` ? I've not had a chance to try this, thus only commenting ;-)