# Mousehover too much delay when pictures change (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing a problem in windowsforms. When I change the backgroundimage of a menubutton the delay is way too long, it takes around 1/2 seconds to change it. The reason why it's happening is not because of my computerspeed, I'm sure of that. Here's my code, I'm looking forward to someone that could help me out.

```
private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Tomb_of_the_Ancients_Portal;
        label1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Toxic_Sewers_Portal;
        label1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Try MouseEnter then.

Comment: I tried MouseEnter, it does not effect the delay on the backgroundImage change, thanks for suggesting it tho.

Comment: Google this: winforms changing backgroundimage slow

Comment: MouseHover has a delay while MouseEnter does not.

Comment: I just compared MouseHover and MouseEnter and MouseEnter was much quicker

Comment: Did you use an eventhandler, does that matter?

Comment: `button1.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { button1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Toxic_Sewers_Portal; label1.Visible = false; };`

Comment: where exactly do I place that in the code? I've got a good feeling about it!

Comment: where ever the button is created or in the constructor if the button is made in the designer

Comment: Ok thanks alot, I'll have to restart my pc because I did not run with debugger. I'm trying it as soon as possible!

Comment: If you don't see any performance difference in using MouseEnter then the performance issue is probably with the image itself. It might be better to have a property that gets the value of your image once instead of using Resources every time. I saw another answer of a question mention image resizing every time can take a while too. Would be helpful if the image is already sized correctly before assigning it to the backgroundimage.

Comment: ok I'll try that. the previous thing did not work, there still is a delay.

Comment: I did remove the ImageLayout.Stretch, but there still is a little, annoying delay. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try some of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778095/windows-forms-using-backgroundimage-slows-down-drawing-of-the-forms-controls)

Comment: I think that the "public static class ControlHelper" is outdated..

Comment: @DutchJelly did you try any of the other answers?

Comment: yes, they unfortunately did not work..

Answer (score -1):

You can call .Refresh() on the button so it can redraw its graphics.

Comment: where do I exactly call it? on the mouseenter or on the mouseleave?

Comment: on mouse enter, after setting the image.

Comment: It's still not completely instant, but I guess it's faster..

Do you know of any way to make it instant like the colorchange of pretty much all buttons?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the fastest way, I'm sorry :(